# How do I make a dataset private in CKAN v2.0

Tags: authorization, ckan

I have created a dataset in a CKAN installation running CKAN v2.0 (beta) and want to make the dataset private (i.e. visible only to me, and possibly a few others in my organization group).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beta isn't released yet,but the functionality currently live at http://preview.ckan.org allows you to restrict by Organization as follows, for a dataset that is in an Organization that you are also a member of:

From the Edit page for your dataset, select 'Private' from  the 'Visibility' drop-down. It can then be seen only by other users in the Organisation.

Comment: Where is the visibility drop-down. I can't see on the edit page. Could you provide a screenshot or similar indicating its location?

Comment: See http://www.flickr.com/photos/okfn/8452054259/. Was there an Organization which both owned the dataset in question and included you as a member?